# R Highchart heatmap with motion, but motion bar is overlapping with x axis

Tags: r, highcharts, heatmap, motion

I tried to create a heatmap with motion in R package Highcharter. I can create it almost successfully. However, the motion bar is overlapping with x xais. Is there any option I can re-position it? I am using Rstudio with R 4.0.2

Here is how the data look like:
[image]

Here is how the heatmap look like:
[image]

Here is my code to create the heatmap with motion

```
hc2 <- hchart(regfinal, type = "heatmap", hcaes(x = arm1_5, y =arm1_3, value = m4)) %>%
  hc_motion(enabled = TRUE, series = 0, startIndex = 0, labels = c("missing 4 observations", "missing 6 observations")) %>% 
  #hc_colorAxis(min = limits[1], max = limits[2])%>%
  #hc_colorAxis(  stops= con_colr,min=limits[1],max=limits[2])%>%
  #hc_colorAxis(  stops=color_stops(3,c("red", "white","blue")))%>%
  #hc_colors(list('#FF5733', '#fcfafa', '#2E86C1') )%>%
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses=color_classes(c(limits[1],0.01,0.05, limits[2]), c("#f54636","#eb7521","#F8F5F5","#21b9eb")))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(
           series = list(
             borderColor = "#fcfbfa",
             borderWidth = 1,
             animation=(durtion=1000),
              dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
    )) %>%
  # hc_tooltip(formatter = fntltp) %>% 
    hc_legend(align = "right", layout = "vertical",
              margin = 0, verticalAlign = "top",
              y = 25, symbolHeight = 10,
              #set symbole to square instead of circle
              symbolRadius=0)%>%
 hc_xAxis(title=list(text="arm_1_5"))%>%
  hc_yAxis(title=list(text="arm1_3") )
 
hc2
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Setting the margin does not fix this problem? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

Comment: I tried to add it into R code.But does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: hc2 <- hchart(regfinal, type = "heatmap", hcaes(x = arm1_5, y =arm1_3, value = m4, marginbottom=150, spacingBottom=150))